# Error: module ‘main:Course’ is defined in multiple files: src/Course.hs

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghci

I'm trying to start working on https://github.com/system-f/fp-course. After running `stack ghci`, it finishes with:

```
...
[51 of 51] Compiling Test.Loader      ( src/Test/Loader.hs, interpreted )
Ok, 51 modules loaded.
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/lpied/haskell/fp-course/.ghci

<no location info>: error:
    module ‘main:Course’ is defined in multiple files: src/Course.hs
                                                       src/Course.hs
Failed, 51 modules loaded.
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/haskell-stack-ghci/75d10d48/ghci-script
```

Any idea why it's complaining that the module is defined in the same file (`src/Course.hs`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try using `stack exec ghci` instead? `stack ghci` is probably recognizing the `src` directory and adding `-isrc` to the `ghci` command line, and then the `.ghci` file in the course root directory is also adding `-isrc` to the `ghci` command line. GHC probably doesn't de-duplicate its search path, so it acts like you have two separate directories which both happen to be named `src`.

Comment: The course is not designed to be used with Stack nor Cabal. It's only designed to be used with a plain ghci.

Comment: @BrianMcKenna Yeah, I guess I was going by what's in the readme "If you are a more experienced developer with tooling set up, and you need a cabal file, shell.nix or stack.yaml to have working development tools, run the support/copy-tool-files.sh script from the root of the repository." and I had stack working, so went with that.